Request to ban the tag "logic"
For example:

"What is Nagarjuna's Tetralemma?"
-> [buddhist-logic] [indian-philosophy] [nagarjuna]

"Logic and critical thinking"
-> [critical-thinking] [argumentation]

"Trivialism "inside" a paraconsistent logic?"
-> [paraconsistent-logic] [philosophy-of-logic] [trivialism]

"If physics can be reduced to mathematics (and thus to logic), does this mean that (physical) causation is ultimately reducible to implication?"
-> [philosophy-of-science] [causation] [implication]

"Possible variants of T-schema"
-> [formal-logic] [truth-conditional-semantics] [metalogic]

"How do you separate premises in logic?"
-> [formal-logic] [argument-structure] [premises]

"Does having a solid logic foundation necessarily guarantee good common sense faculty?"
-> [practical-reasoning] [critical-thinking] [common-sense]

"Can these statements really be arguments?"
-> [argumentation] [informal-logic] [propositions]

"Disjoint predicates FOL: equivalence of normal forms"
-> [first-order-logic] [predicate-logic] [formal-semantics]

"Can logic exist outside of a linguistic framework?"
-> [philosophy-of-logic] [philosophy-of-language] [cognition]

"Are there unsolved paradoxes?"
-> [paradoxes] [philosophy-of-logic] [history-of-logic]

"Is there any mathematically valid statement that defies logic?"
-> [philosophy-of-mathematics] [mathematical-logic] [metamathematics]

"General reasoning as numerical optimization?"
-> [reasoning] [cognitive-science] [computational-philosophy]

"Epimenides paradox inside arithmetic"
-> [mathematical-logic] [paradoxes] [foundations-of-mathematics]




Context: The ‘logic’ tag is problematically overused

Given that any question about a form of logic can be tagged with that form (or such a tag created if necessary), or a question about logic in general will either have more appropriate tags related to e.g. nature or history or philosophy or whatever particular aspect thereof, or just be straight-up too broad anyway, this seems like a good tag to be burninated and blocked.
